# Powershell - Using a .htm file as the body of an email

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a powershell script that will be kicked off by a scheduled task, the script will return details of our database backups, save these to a .htm file and also email the results.

So far getting the backup info and saving to a .htm file works fine, but I can't figure out how to get the body of the email to look like the .htm file. The email body at the moment looks like the raw html code.

So far:

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyyMMdd')





[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "LOCALHOST\SQLX64"

$dbs=$s.Databases

#Retrieves the last backup dates - both for FULL and LOG backups

$backups = $dbs | SELECT Name,LastBackupDate, LastLogBackupDate | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>Database Backup Details $date </H2>" | Out-File $("D:\SQL Backup Log Script\Logs\"+ $date +"_DB01 Backup Log.htm")


$EmailFrom = "IT@##.net"
$emailto = "##@##.net"
$Subject = "DB01 SQL Backup Log" 
$Body = Get-Content ("D:\SQL Backup Log Script\Logs\"+ $date +"_Backup Log.htm")
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("##", "##"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Thanks,
Charlotte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this line before send() method:

```
$SMTPClient.isbodyhtml= $true
```

EDIT after comment:

You have to use this object:

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Comment: Thanks but that's not working : Property 'isbodyhtml' cannot be found on this object

Comment: - Edit answer. You need to change .net object for fill your necessities.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347693.aspx) cmdlet instead, which allows you to specify the `-BodyAsHtml` parameter:

```
Send-MailMessage `
    -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo `
    -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml $true `
    -Credential $Credentials
```

Alternatively you will have to use the [SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) method instead and create a [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) object where you can set the [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) property:

```
var client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
# ...
var message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
message.IsBodyHtml = $true
# ...
$client.Send($message)
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be ideal but I can't use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet to send emails vis the gmail smtp server.

Answer (score 3):

collected all the answers in one piece:

```
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("##", "##"); 
$message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $true;
$SMTPClient.Send($message)
```